# Angular factory does not keep data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory in my AngularJS (version 1.4) application.
The code is in the main `app.js` file:

```
.factory('UserPreferences', function($http, URL, AuthService, store){

    var userPreferences = {
        "face_shape": '',
        "lifestyle": '',
        "hair_texture": '',
        "email": '',
        "postcode": '',
        "full_name": '',
        "password": ''
    };

    return {
        save_face_shape: function(face_shape){
            userPreferences.face_shape = face_shape;
            console.log(userPreferences); // -> LINE 307
        },
        save_lifestyle: function(lifestyle){
            userPreferences.lifestyle = lifestyle;
            console.log(userPreferences); // -> LINE 311
        },
        save_hair_texture: function(texture){
            userPreferences.hair_texture = texture;
        },
        get_data: function(){
            return userPreferences;
        }
    }
}). // -> here's another factory
```

What I'm trying to do is to save the user prefernces through different steps in the application, and after a trigger event save the whole user in the database.

In the controller of the page where I do that I have the following code:

```
$scope.triggerSecondStep = function(shape){
    UserPreferences.save_face_shape(shape);
    $scope.step = 2;
}

$scope.triggerThirdStep = function(lifestyle){
    UserPreferences.save_lifestyle(lifestyle);
    $scope.step = 3;
}
```

In the controller's view I call those function in a very simple way:

```
 <img ng-click="triggerSecondStep('square')" class='hover-opacity' ng-src="LINK_IMAGE" />
```

Since it was not working I added some `console.log` to print out intermediate step. What I found out is that the `console.log` on the line 307 prints the following output when I call `triggerSecondStep`:

```
app.js:307 Object {face_shape: "round", lifestyle: "", hair_texture: "", email: "", postcode: ""…}
app.js:307 Object {face_shape: undefined, lifestyle: "", hair_texture: "", email: "", postcode: ""…}
```

The output of the `console.log` at line 311 is the following:

```
app.js:311 Object {face_shape: undefined, lifestyle: "busy", hair_texture: "", email: "", postcode: ""…}
app.js:311 Object {face_shape: undefined, lifestyle: undefined, hair_texture: "", email: "", postcode: ""…}
```

So basically I can't figure out why the data are not stored from one call to another, and why the `console.log` prints twice the output instead of just of just once.

Anyone can help?

EDIT:

Updating the question after reading the comments (thanks btw).

If I add some `console.log` in the `triggerSecondStep`:

```
$scope.triggerSecondStep = function(shape){
    console.log(shape);
    UserPreferences.save_face_shape(shape);
    console.log(UserPreferences.get_data());
    $scope.step = 2;
}
```

This is the output (landing_compiled is simply the compiled version of landing.js, with babel):

```
square
app.js:308 Object {face_shape: "square", lifestyle: "", hair_texture: "", email: "", postcode: ""…}
landing.compiled.js:72 Object {face_shape: "square", lifestyle: "", hair_texture: "", email: "", postcode: ""…}
landing.compiled.js:70 undefined
app.js:308 Object {face_shape: undefined, lifestyle: "", hair_texture: "", email: "", postcode: ""…}
landing.compiled.js:72 Object {face_shape: undefined, lifestyle: "", hair_texture: "", email: "", postcode: ""…}
```

If I add `debugger;` at line 307 I see the following stackstrace:

[image]

Once I get to the last step (`r.handle`) it just start over again, this time with no parameter.

Comment: Do you have any other references to `triggerSecondStep` at all? It looks as though somewhere you have something else calling it without a parameter and that overwrites the value you just saved.

Comment: Add a `debugger;` statement at line :307 and open the inspector when running the script. You can check the stacktrace to see who called this method. One of them should be `$scope.triggerSecondStep`

Comment: Can you log the data as it comes into your controller function? e.g. $scope.triggerSecondStep = function(shape){ console.log(shape)
    UserPreferences.save_face_shape(shape);
    $scope.step = 2;
}

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you put this in a plunkr it would work as expected. The problem is probably outside the code you are showing us, something is probably declared twice or something of that sort.

Answer (score 1):

You guys were right: basically outside the image element that triggered the function `triggerSecondStep` there was a `div` calling the same function on `ng-click`:

```
<div ng-click="triggerSecondStep()" class='title-widget margin-bottom'>What's your face <span class='transparent-font'>shape</span>?</div>
...
...
...
 <img ng-click="triggerSecondStep('square')" class='hover-opacity' ng-src="LINK_IMAGE" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I've created fiddle with the same data, use for your reference:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tG46g/23/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the Fiddle, I can see that is working...what could be the problem in my application?

Comment: can you update your data with fiddle so that I can check?Or else you update your question bit more?